# Как проверить регистр слов с нерусскими (не латинские) символами?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Имеется большое количество текста в документе Word содержащий символы, которые отсутствуют в русском языке.
Какой функцией (способами) можно осуществить проверку регистра слов в Delphi?
Т.е. как отделить все прописные слова идущие подряд как единое целое?
Неважно как: прямо из Word или через RichEdit. Сам начал и до конца не смог закончить. Т.е. не смог реализовать самую нужную функцию.
Рисунок с вышеупомянутыми символами прилагаю.

[image: Символы отсутствующие в русской раскладке]

Answer (score 1):

```
if SysUtils.AnsiSameStr(SysUtils.AnsiLowerCase(WordFromText), WordFromText) then
  ... // WordFromText содержит только маленькие буквы
else
  ... // WordFromText содержит большие буквы
```

Comment: Только что проверил, в Delphi 7 тоже есть эти функции.

Comment: **Krom Stern**, **kot-da-vinci** спасибо за ответ! Сегодня как раз использовал вот эту - AnsiUpperCase. Пока не подсказали, я думал, что эти функции преобразовывают текст а не проверяют. Мне же нужна была именно проверяющая. В общем думаю смогу довести задачу до ума.